# Javascript Client side Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

Does anyone know how to employ a fully function javascript client side validation?. Say we have a form with a fields for name, address, contact number, age, date and we want to validate. I have done this using regExpressions but need someone experts code to look and compare with it. Many thanks and do reply

Comment: Can you  use jQuery? In this case, this is a nice plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? There are many validation libraries built on them, or vanilla...the best answer would come from knowing what (if anything) you're already using.

Comment: No. I have been asked by my manager to get it done using Javascript and not using any tables for the form layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no 'expert', but I began writing my own client-side input validator not long ago. You can see the code at https://github.com/kaimallea/input-validator.

Answer (score 3):

this is a nice one : [jquery-form-validator](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

and another one :
[How to Validate Forms in both sides using PHP and jQuery](http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/how-validate-forms-both-sides-using-php-jquery/)

and [here](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/validateform/) is a demo how it will look

Comment: thanks the second link is good but is not a comprehensive answer!